# Gson get unused data in java class POJO

Tags: java, json, gson

I am developing an API that reads data generate by another program. The data is in a json format and I want to use Gson to read that json data into a json object and also report any unused data that hasn't been specified in the class. For example, I have this json:

```
{"Event": "ChatMessageSent", "Message": "This is a test message!", "Time":1628466226}
```

Now, the class only has the Event String and Message String, so it will only store that data. My question is how can I set up my POJO Class or get Gson to also return the Time data in a special method that returns all unused data, so it can be sent to a debug log for throwing a warning for unused data. Since the data may change at any version, I need to create a logging system that tells me if the API missed some data.

Any pointers are much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Gson, but in Jackson you'd either use `@JsonAnySetter` (to collect unknown properties) or use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` (to generate an exception). You might see if Gson has an equivalent.

Comment: I've looked at this, and it looks like a switch to Jackson would be the best way and does exactly what I need, I will try this and report back if this is a solution I am going with.

Comment: Your description sounds like a server application, but note that if you're writing for Android, Gson has substantial optimizations for the constraints of that platform and is the default.

Comment: Currently, I am not planing to use this on android, but I will note this if I decide to use android and Gson in the future, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score -1):

How about creating a custom GSon deserializer for the fields you need. You could look into [TypeAdaptor](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html).

Comment: Could you elaborate how this can help me to filter out unused data/unknown properties